# JSF PrimeFaces rowSelect for one datatable being called from another datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable

I have a `Purchase` datatable in a tab that lists all purchases. When you select a row, it is supposed to open a dialog that shows a list of the purchases for a particular customer. Also in the code there is a dialog for adding a new purchase in which a `Customer` can be selected from a list of previous customers in a datatable.

My problem is that when I select a row in the purchase table it is calling the `rowSelect` ajax event in the customer datatable (from inside the "New Purchase" dialog) instead of triggering it's own `rowSelect` event that opens the `Purchase` dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <h:form id="newPurchaseCommandForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:commandButton value="New Purchase" process="@this"
            onclick="PF('newPurchase').show()" id="btnNewPurchase">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{purchasesDAO.init()}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>

    <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true" scrollable="true"
        style="font-size:12px;">

        <p:tab id="tba1" title="Purchase List">
            <h:form id="purchaseTableForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:dataTable id="PurchaseTable" var="purchaseVar"
                    rowKey="#{purchaseVar.id}"
                    selection="#{purchasesDAO.selectedPurchaseRow}"
                    widgetVar="purchasesTableSearch"
                    filteredValue="#{purchasesDAO.filteredPurchaseRow}"
                    selectionMode="single" value="#{purchasesDAO.purchaseList}"
                    style="font-size:10px;">

                    <!-- Opens dialog -->
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{purchasesDAO.onRowSelect}"
                        update=":messages" oncomplete="PF('showPurchase').show()" />

...
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

    <p:dialog header="Purchase Details" widgetVar="showPurchase"
        id="dialog" resizable="true" modal="false" hideEffect="explode"
        height="500" width="990">

...

    </p:dialog>


    <p:dialog header="Add New Purchase" widgetVar="newPurchase"
        id="dialogNewPurchase" resizable="true" modal="true" hideEffect="explode"
        closeOnEscape="true" height="600" width="900">
        <h:form id="form-newcasedialog" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:dataTable id="CustomerTable" var="customer"
                rowKey="#{customer.id}"
                selection="#{purchasesDAO.selectedCustomerRow}"
                widgetVar="purchasesTableSearch"
                filteredValue="#{purchasesDAO.filteredCustomerRow}"
                selectionMode="single" value="#{purchasesDAO.customerList}"
                style="font-size:10px;">

                <!-- Opens dialog -->

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{purchasesDAO.onRowSelect3}"
                    process="@this" />
...
                </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this took me ages to find but it turned out to be a simple one-line typo.
The `widgetVar` for both the Customer table and the Purchases table were the same:

```
<p:dataTable id="CustomerTable" var="customer"
    rowKey="#{customer.id}"
     selection="#{purchasesDAO.selectedCustomerRow}"
     widgetVar="purchasesTableSearch"
     filteredValue="#{purchasesDAO.filteredCustomerRow}"
     selectionMode="single" value="#{purchasesDAO.customerList}"
     style="font-size:10px;">
```

Should be:

```
<p:dataTable id="CustomerTable" var="customer"
    rowKey="#{customer.id}"
     selection="#{purchasesDAO.selectedCustomerRow}"
     widgetVar="customerTableSearch"
     filteredValue="#{purchasesDAO.filteredCustomerRow}"
     selectionMode="single" value="#{purchasesDAO.customerList}"
     style="font-size:10px;">
```

This was caused by copy/pasting code during development and missing the `widgetVar` line when updating the code. Changing the `widgetVar` in the customer datatable to be different to the purchase table solved the problem.